# Confusing problem statement of exercise 7.4.3 in Wasserman's All of statistics

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I am reading chapter 7 of Larry Wasserman's All of statistics and working on the exercises in the end of this chapter. The exercise 7.4.3 (on p. 104) states:

> (Computer Experiment.) Generate 100 observations from a N(O,1) dis-
>   tribution. Compute a 95 percent confidence band for the CDF F (as
>   described in the appendix). Repeat this 1000 times and see how often
>   the confidence band contains the true distribution function. Repeat
>   us- ing data from a Cauchy distribution.

Does anybody know what appendix does the author refer to? This chapter or the book itself do not have any appendices.

Comment: maybe it's a typo

Comment: is there any useful information on pages 99-100, which aren't available in the Google Books view I was just looking at?

Comment: Well, there are examples there.

Answer (score 1):

Confidence band for the CDF can be constructed using the Dvoretzky-Kiefer-Wolfowitz (DKW) Inequality (see theorem 7.5 in the book and what follows after it on page 99).